Simple counter example to show that identity function is not homotopic to the constant

A continous function $f:X \to Y$ is called homotopy equivalence, wenn there is a function $g$ with the property that $g \circ f \simeq id_X$ and $f \circ g \simeq id_Y$. Remark: Homotopy considered here is that of free homotopy, that is, relative to empty set.

Given any two topological spaces $X,Y$ it is quite easy to construct a function between them which satisfies these conditions. Pick a point $y \in Y$ and define a function $f: X \to Y$ as $f(x) = y$, and similarly pick a point $x \in X$ and define $g: Y \to X$ as $g(y) = x$.
The constant functions are always continous, hence $g,f$ are continous. Now, I am trying to find a simple counter example where the  compositions that could be created from this pair could never be homotopic to identity on either space with a proof of the non existence of the homotopy function.
Could one be provided?

Perhaps for more context, I calculate out an example where they actually are. Consider $\mathbb{R^2}$ and the space of just a point $\{ * \}$. We construct $f: \mathbb{R^2}$ and $g: \mathbb{R^2}$ by the prescription above. The homotopy between $g \circ f $ and identity is given as $\mathcal{H}: \mathbb{R^2} \times I \to \mathbb{R^2}$ as $\mathcal{H}(x,t) = t* x$, $ f \circ g$ is just the identity function on the point space, so it is trivial that it is homotopic to the identity (via homotopy being a reflexive relation)
Maybe a remark on why this question is  actually somewhat hard: The point space is actually quite nice topologically. It is path connected, hausdorf, compact, normal and what not. So the non existence can not be given through usage of topological invariants.

Let $X$ be any space with more than one point which has the discrete topology. Then the identity function is not homotopic to a constant function.
In fact, each homotopy $H : X \times I \to X$ such that $H(x,0) = x$ maps the path connected subspace $L_x = \{x\} \times I \subset X \times I$ to the path connected subspace $L'_x = H(L_x) \subset X$. The path component of $x$ is the singleton $\{x\}$. Since $x \in L'_x$, we conclude $L'_x \subset \{x\}$, i.e. $L'_x = \{x\}$. This shows that $H$ is stationary: $H(x,t) = x$ for all $(x,t)$.
A less trivial example is the unit circle $S^1$. The identity on $S^1$ is not homotopic to any constant map. A proof can be found in any textbook about algebraic topology. There are also many questions in this forum dealing with it.

Which invariant is used exactly?

@CantorDustDrachen: Contrary to the closing sentence of your post, topological invariants which distinguish a 1 point space from other spaces are exactly what one uses to construct counterexamples of this kind. For the first counterexample given in this answer, you can use path connectedness: a discrete space with one point is path connected; a discrete space with more than one point is not path connected.
